# Draw with tikz in a beamer document

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I need to make a 1D draw for a random walk. The problem is that beamer doesn't let me use the same code I used for "report". And I don't know what's wrong, It's exactly the same I used

It shows me this message:

*Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:\Users\Sergio1\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log*

And the code I used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}
    \usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
    
    
    \begin{document}
     \begin{frame}    
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; 
         \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x-2h$},-3/{$x-h$},0/{$x$},3/{$x+h$},6/{$x+2h$}}              
         \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};
         \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}
         \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4, shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt, blue, thick](\x,0)to node[ label=90: 1/2]{}(\y,0);
          \draw (-6,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$h \mathbb{Z}$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

EDIT: I checked the log and it shows this, no idea what it means

*2021-04-16 10:52:31,168+0200 INFO  texify - this process (12816) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean TFG-diapositiva.tex

2021-04-16 10:52:31,213+0200 INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex --synctex=1 "C:/Users/Sergio1/Desktop/Cosas de la Uni/TFG/Mi trabajo\TFG-diapositiva.tex"

2021-04-16 10:52:34,075+0200 FATAL texify.core - TeX engine failed for some reason (see log file).
2021-04-16 10:52:34,076+0200 FATAL texify.core - Data:

2021-04-16 10:52:34,076+0200 FATAL texify.core - Source:
Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1528

2021-04-16 10:52:34,080+0200 FATAL texify - TeX engine failed for some reason (see log file).

2021-04-16 10:52:34,080+0200 FATAL texify - Info:

2021-04-16 10:52:34,080+0200 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp

2021-04-16 10:52:34,080+0200 FATAL texify - Line: 1528

2021-04-16 10:52:34,082+0200 ERROR texify - minor issue: It has been a long time since a MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates*

Comment: It is better to wrap the body of the `\foreach` loop in `{...}` such that it is clear what is part of the loop

Comment: Your code is correct (here, it compiles very well). What errors do you see in the file `C:\Users\Sergio1\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\texify.log`?

Comment: @Serch For me, your code is working... Do you have some other libraries etc. in your preamble?

Comment: No @Excelsior,  that's everything I have on my code. That's what bothers me. On \documentclass{report} it works perfectly

Comment: @PaulGaborit. I updated the question with the log

Comment: Your example works fine in pdflatex on TeX Live. So this is likely a bug in MikTeX. The bugtracker is at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Comment: What errors do you see in the file `C:/Users/Sergio1/Desktop/Cosas de la Uni/TFG/Mi trabajo\TFG-diapositiva.log`?

Comment: @PaulGaboritv !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi10): Font mathkerncmssi10 at 657 not
 found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!    . And on line 657: ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/beamer\beamercolorthemedefault.sty")

Comment: Try to check for updates for MikTeX (as administrator)...

Comment: For debugging texify might not be a good idea as it seems to hide the actual error message. When I used your example I got errors about `\x`, and after adding the `{...}` I mentioned above, it compiled for me.

Comment: @daleif I took another look. And the loop is not the problem, the problem is actually in " \draw[\shift=..."

Answer (score 1):

Your current code compiles fine for me on TeXLive 2021. But I would suggest rewriting the `\foreach` like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}
    \usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
    
    
    \begin{document}
     \begin{frame}    
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; 
         \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x-2h$},-3/{$x-h$},0/{$x$},3/{$x+h$},6/{$x+2h$}}{              
           \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};
         }
         \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}{
           \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4, shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt, blue, thick](\x,0)to node[ label=90: 1/2]{}(\y,0);
         }
          \draw (-6,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$h \mathbb{Z}$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

Then it is much clearer when `\x` and `\y` are defined.

Answer (score 1):

In one loop, using Ti*k*Z libraries `arrows.meta` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
%                babel,     % not needed in this MWE
                quotes,
%                svg.path   % not needed in this MWE
                }


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[-Straight Barb] 
        (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$h\in\mathbb{Z}$};
\foreach \i [count=\j from -2] in  {x-2h,x-h,x,x+h,x+2h}%
 {
 \draw  (2*\j,3pt) -- ++ (0,-6pt) node[below] {$\i$};
 \ifnum\j<2
 \draw [blue, thick, bend left=45, 
        shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt]
        (2*\j,0) to ["1/2"] ++ (2,0);
 \fi
 }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out how to do it. It's messy, but that's the only way I found out

I just used the code on the report document, took the page where the image is located, used photospot to get the png of the draw, and manually introduce it to the beamer with \includegraphics

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem comes from the `shift` argument, you can try my approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}
%\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={font=\strut}, % <- same size for all nodes
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75] % scaling to fit the frame
%           \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0); <- you define it again below  
            \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x-2h$},-3/{$x-h$},0/{$x$},3/{$x+h$},6/{$x+2h$}}{%
                \draw[color=black]  (\x,3pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[below] {\y};
            }
            
            \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}{%
                \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4,shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt,blue,thick](\x,0) to node[above]{1/2}(\y,0);
            }
            
            \draw[-stealth] (-6,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$h \mathbb{Z}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```